# Html/Javascript debugging in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, javascript, debugging, webview, javafx

Are there any ways to debug javascript and html that is executed within a Javafx WebView?  Something similar to Firebug or Chrome's developer console?

I have an application that renders fine in Firefox and Chrome, but does not render correctly inside a WebView.  It really could be any number of things, but without some debugging tools I don't know how to track down the root cause.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is some Java code to make use of Firebug Lite in a JavaFX WebView without modifying the html of the target page.

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript("if (!document.getElementById('FirebugLite')){E = document['createElement' + 'NS'] && document.documentElement.namespaceURI;E = E ? document['createElement' + 'NS'](E, 'script') : document['createElement']('script');E['setAttribute']('id', 'FirebugLite');E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + 'firebug-lite.js' + '#startOpened');E['setAttribute']('FirebugLite', '4');(document['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0] || document['getElementsByTagName']('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E = new Image;E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + '#startOpened');}");
```

You can trigger the code using a JavaFX Button or any other mechanism you wish.

Comment: You need to make sure that you wait for the document to load before starting Firebug. See jewelsea's answer here for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18396900/633107

Comment: @ZiglioNZ please ask new questions as new questions.

Comment: The url does not work any more. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521474/how-to-include-firebug-light-without-access-to-http-getfirebug-com

Answer (score 10):

I am debugging JavaFx WebView with chrome DevTools and safari Web Inspector.

I created minimal project to help people debug with DevTools. [Get it on GitHub](https://github.com/mohamnag/javafx_webview_debugger). You can find there:

1. runnable javaFXWebKitDebugger.jar
2. source code of created javaFXWebKitDebugger.jar

The sample opens WebView and enables WebSocket Servlet. When you run javaFXWebKitDebugger.jar open Chrome browser and load: [dev tools url](http://chrome-devtools//devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:51742/devtools/page/1)

Comment: I really like what you have achieved there, but it seems you are using some deprecated APIs.

Comment: Please place this piece of code on github instead of Google Drive. Also please release it under some open source license.

Comment: @bosko-popovic could you please solve the mystery of this code's license? I just republished your code on GitHub for better usage and I'm getting request to define a license for it, but this is actually your decision to respond to. take a look here: https://github.com/mohamnag/javafx_webview_debugger/issues/1

Comment: This code has open source license dependency. I am glad that I can help someone with this, since I spent days trying to include debugger.

Comment: webEngine.impl_getDebugger() appears to be deprecated, and I am getting class not found exception for javafx.servlet.Servlet when attempting to run the program. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 6):

You can try Firebug Lite, which can be incorporated into any web-browser. See http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-firebug-for-browsers-other-than-firefox/

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late to answer, but I think this way is quite simple.

add javascript listener in java

Java :

```
webengine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable,
                    State oldValue, State newValue) { 
                     JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webengine.executeScript("window");                      
                     jsobj.setMember("java", new JSListener());  
            }
        });
```

Then create the JS listener class in java.

JSListener java:

```
public class JSListener { 

        public void log(String text){
    System.out.println(text);
} 
}
```

add javascript in html file

Javascript:

```
var javaReady = function(callback){
    if(typeof callback =='function'){
        if(typeof java !='undefined'){
            callback();
        } else {
            var javaTimeout = 0;
            var readycall = setInterval(function(){
            javaTimeout++; 
                if(typeof java !='undefined' || javaTimeout > 1000){
                    try{
                        callback();
                    } catch(s){};
                    clearInterval(readycall);
                }
            },1);
        }
    }
};

            var errorlistener = function(msg, url, line){ 
            javaReady(function(){
            java.log(msg +", url: "+url+ ", line:" + line); 
            }); 
        };

      //overide onerror 
        var onerror = errorlistener;
```

If you want to load html from the outside, you can not to change it, you can use code like this.

```
var testsss =  window.open("http://testError.com");  
testsss.onerror = errorlistener;
```

but first you need to add setCreatePopupHandler in java, to make it you can see here: [webview not opening the popup window in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370622/webview-not-opening-the-popup-window-in-javafx)

Comment: Now that `import netscape.javascript.JSObject;` is deprecated in java 9 and `import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;` was removed from the JDK in Java 15 what is the current solution to getting a `JSObject`?