# Call firebug lite methods from javafx 2.2 webengine

Tags: javascript, javafx-2, firebug-lite

I want to execute Firebug lite in my webengine and then call some methods from the script. First i execute the script as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview) and its work fine. The problem starts when I try to call and execute a method inside from the script. First I have a 'Exit' button in the webview and in the event of the button i call the method shutdown to close the script. Below is the code:

```
eng.executeScript("window.Firebug.shutdown();");
```

The firebug immediately disappears from the webview. Then I have another button 'Start' and in the event i want to open again firebug with the code below, but nothing happens. No errors or exceptions appear and seems that the script executes correctly.

```
eng.executeScript("window.Firebug.startOpened=true;");
```

I also try the method initialize() `eng.executeScript("window.Firebug.initialize();");`and then i get an exception like below:

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1438)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:811)
at student.WebBrowser$2.handle(WebBrowser.java:126)
```

I also want to know which method in the script executes when the user clicks the ShowInNewWindow button and from an JSObject in javafx catch the event and open firebug in a new form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that window.Firebug exists?  The script you linked to adds a FirebugLite element, not Firebug.

Comment: I believe that exists because when I call windows.Firebug.Shutdown(); Firebug  disappears form the screen.