# Debug JavaFX web view with weinre

Tags: javafx-2, weinre

Has anyone tried to debug a webpages rendered in a javafx web view with weinre? Is this possible or is web view lacking the necessary infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

As the Weinre interface to the browser is just JavaScript and JavaScript executes just fine in WebView, WebView has the "necessary infrastructure" to use weinre.

To give an indication of how to execute JavaScript within the context of WebView, you can look at the code I used to debug WebView using the JavaScript based Firebug Lite tool: [Html/Javascript debugging in JavaFX WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview).  The code is a slightly modified version of the code found in the Firebug Lite bookmarklet.  As Weinre also has a bookmarklet which can be used to initiate it, you could perform a similar translation for Weinre as I did for Firebug Lite.

Additionally Weinre is usable by placing a script tag inside the target web page.  Take a look at some [sample code](https://gist.github.com/3077942) that I created for embedding the jQuery script library into WebView - you could do the same for the Weinre script library.

I doubt anybody has tried using WebView with Weinre before.