# how to open pop up in new window using javafx web view

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to implement popup handler in javafx webview its generating the popup and adding it on the same fxpanel but i want to display it onto the new window . I am using the following code.

```
 try
 {

 Webview webview,smallView
 final Group group= new Group();
 Scene scene= new Scene(group);
 fxpanel.setScene(scene);    
 webview = new WebView ();
 group.getChildren().add(webview);
 eng= webview.getEngine();

  String url ="http://www.timetrim.in/webchatserver2/default.aspx";

         eng.load(url);

         smallView = new WebView();
         smallView.setPrefSize(400, 200);


         eng.setCreatePopupHandler(
        new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
            @Override
            public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures config) {
            smallView.setFontScale(0.8);
            if (!group.getChildren().contains(smallView)) {
                group.getChildren().add(smallView);
            }
            return smallView.getEngine();

            }
    }); 

    }

   catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370622/webview-not-opening-the-popup-window-in-javafx/16372083#16372083