# How to debug JavaFx WebView outgoing requests?

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview, urlconnection

I need to debug all outgoing requests from WebView and find as much as possible ( request headers, POST/PUT parameters, etc. ). I need to load the traffic data in Java, therefore Firebug is not a solution.

In other words I want to monitor the complete outgoing activity and get as much information as possible. In special when is related to some user interaction ( pressing a button, link, etc. ). I am building a Web testing platform and I need to track the HttpRequests created in WebView and get data in Java.

Possible solutions I was thinking on :

- After the page is loaded run a JavaScript which listen to the
  requests and pass the data through shared objects between WebView and
  Java ( https://gist.github.com/lczx/268eb7cd7b079af1bd17 )
- Create a Proxy
- Manupulate some URL or Java objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html/Javascript debugging in JavaFX WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. The other thread is debugging using JavaScript and the result is visible only in Firebug. I want be able to load the script data in Java ( the WebView is running in Java ) and just to listen to the WebView outgoing traffic.  I am writing a Testing platform for Web applications, and I need to be able to 'catch' the user interaction HttpRequest parameters, like PUT, GET, POST; etc.